# How to deal with heterogeneous data sources in repository pattern?

Tags: android, design-patterns, repository-pattern, android-architecture-components

Suppose you want to implement a repository patter for handling the data of the app.
Imaging you have two Data Sources:

1. Local cache (or database)
2. Remote service (Rest API)

The service doesn't allow to make changes, but just to retrieve data, so a very simple interface for the data source could be

```
interface DataSource {
   suspend fun getClients(): Result<List<Client>> 
   suspend fun getClient(): Result<Client>
}
```

Both `remoteDataSource` and `cacheDataSource` will implement it.

However, the `cacheDataSource` needs to be filled with the data, so it would need an extra function, something like suspend fun `addClients(clients: List<Client>)`, so I could be change the interface into:

```
interface DataSource {
   suspend fun getClients(): Result<List<Client>> 
   suspend fun getClient(): Result<Client>
   suspend fun addClients(clients: List<Client>)
}
```

This however would be bad, as the `remoteDataSource` will not implement addClients.

So I could remove that function from that interface and make `cacheDataSource` to implement another interface:

```
interface CacheClients {
   suspend fun cacheData(clients: List<Client>)
}
```

The problem is now that my repository, which should just receive two instances of DataSource, wouldn't know about the other interface that the `cacheDataSource` is implementing.

What do you think is the best approach in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mostly on correct path but your repository should at all times know from which data source the data will come from weather it is fetched over network or a local data source.

Hence when your VM requests some data from the repo layer the repo layer should decide where this data will come from. It will first check the local data source then if data is unavailable then it will fetch it over network.

Thus your repository should have a data source which would be a direct child of an interface which will in turn be a child of both Local and Remote Data Source interfaces.

Sample code

```
interface DataSource(){
  Result<List<Client>> getClients();
  Result<Client> getClient();
}

interface Cache(){
  void caheClientData(Result<Client> data); 
}

// Marker Interace
interface CacheEnabledDataSource implements DataSource, Cache{}

class Repository{
 CacheEnabledDataSource source;
}
```